# c++ function template specify second template parameter type

Tags: c++, templates

just started learning template programming, I have the following code,

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void add(T x, U y)
{
    cout<< x + y <<endl;
}
```

I can call this by,

```
add(1, 2);
add<int, int>(1, 2);
add<int>(1, 2.0);
```

In the third case, I believe that means I specified `[T=int]`, and compiler will deduce `[U=double]`

My question is how can I specify the second parameter type explicitly?

Comment: If you want to specify second parameter, you have to specify first one too. There are no `add<_, double>`.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to specify `U` but not `T`? That's not possible.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It sounds as if `add<int,double>(1, 2.0)` or `add<int>(1, float(2.0))` might be what you want, but it seems too obvious a solution.

Comment: @KenY-N Seems like this could be what he was trying to ask but still unclear

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude by saying "not possible", I'm sure someone's going to take up the challenge to devise a way to do just that!

Comment: @KenY-N Then good for them! And the OP :)

Comment: @tesla1060 What is the *real* problem you want to solve? *Why* do you want to do whatever you want to do? This has the typical smell of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deduce first template parameter in multiple parameter template by parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034883/deduce-first-template-parameter-in-multiple-parameter-template-by-parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about `add(1,(int)2.0);`.

In theory according to *template argument deduction* rules, this causes the second template parameter to be deduced as `int`.So this is stricktly *equivalent* to this hypothetical syntax `add<U=int>(1,2.0);`

So this is the way to specify the second template argument!

It is impossible to find an equivalent syntax if the second template argument is non-deductible:

```
template<class T>
struct t_{
  using type = T;
  };

template<class T,class U>
auto add(T, typename t_<U>::type);
```

Comment: `add<auto, int>(1, 2.0);` - hypothetical as well, but more C++ like... Hm, might propose that for C++20...